# String matching with wildcards, trying Biostrings package

Tags: r

Given the string `patt`:

```
patt = "AGCTTCATGAAGCTGAGTNGGACGCGATGATGCG"
```

We can make a collection of shorter substrings `str_col`:

```
str_col = substring(patt,1:(nchar(patt)-9),10:nchar(patt))
```

which we want to match against a `subject1`:

```
subject1 = "AGCTTCATGAAGCTGAGTGGGACGCGATGATGCGACTAGGGACCTTAGCAGC"
```

treating "N" in `patt` as a wildcard (match to any letter in `subject1`), so all substrings in `str_col` match to `subject1`.

I want to do this kind of string matching in a large database of strings, and I found the `Bioconductor` package `Biostrings` be very efficient to do that. But, in order to be efficient, Biostrings requires you to convert your collection of substrings (here `str_col`) into a dictionary of class `pdict` using the function `PDidc()`. You can use this 'dictionary' later in functions like `countPDict()` to count matches against a target.

In order to use wildcards, you have to divide your dictionary in 3 parts: a head (left), a trusted band (middle) and a tail (right). You can only have wildcards, like "N", in the head or tail, but not in the trusted band, and you cannot have a trusted band of width = 0. So, for example, `str_col[15]` won't match if you use a trusted band of minimum width = 1 like:

```
> PDict(str_col[1:15],tb.start=5,tb.end=5)
Error in .Call2("ACtree2_build", tb, pp_exclude, base_codes, nodebuf_ptr,  :
    non base DNA letter found in Trusted Band for pattern 15
```

because the "N" is right in the trusted band. Notice that the strings here are DNA sequences, so "N" is a code for "match to A, C, G, or T".

```
> PDict(str_col[1:14],tb.start=5,tb.end=5) #is OK
TB_PDict object of length 14 and width 10 (preprocessing algo="ACtree2"):
    - with a head of width 4
    - with a Trusted Band of width 1
    - with a tail of width 5
```

Is there any way to circumvent this limitation of `Biostrings`? I also tried to perform such task using R base functions, but I couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon that you'll need matching against some other wild cards from the [IUPAC ambiguity code](http://www.dnabaser.com/articles/IUPAC%20ambiguity%20codes.html) at one point, no?

If you need perfect matches and base functions are enough for you, you can use the same trick as the function `glob2rx()` : simply use conversion with `gsub()` to construct the matching patterns. An example:

```
IUPACtoRX <- function(x){
  p <- gsub("N","\\[ATCG\\]",x)
  p <- gsub("Y","\\[CT\\]",p)  #match any pyrimidine
  # add the ambiguity codes you want here
  p
}
```

Obviously you need a line for every ambiguity you want to program in, but it's pretty straightforward I'd say.

Doing this, you can then eg do something like:

```
> sapply(str_col, function(i) grepl(IUPACtoRX(i),subject1) )
AGCTTCATGA GCTTCATGAA CTTCATGAAG TTCATGAAGC TCATGAAGCT CATGAAGCTG ATGAAGCTGA 
      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE 
TGAAGCTGAG GAAGCTGAGT AAGCTGAGTN AGCTGAGTNG GCTGAGTNGG CTGAGTNGGA TGAGTNGGAC 
      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE 
GAGTNGGACG AGTNGGACGC GTNGGACGCG TNGGACGCGA NGGACGCGAT GGACGCGATG GACGCGATGA 
      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE 
ACGCGATGAT CGCGATGATG GCGATGATGC CGATGATGCG 
      TRUE       TRUE       TRUE       TRUE
```

To find the number of matches, you can use eg `gregexpr()`:

```
> sapply(str_col,function(i) sum(gregexpr(IUPACtoRX(i),subject1) > 0 ))
AGCTTCATGA GCTTCATGAA CTTCATGAAG TTCATGAAGC TCATGAAGCT CATGAAGCTG ATGAAGCTGA 
         1          1          1          1          1          1          1 
TGAAGCTGAG GAAGCTGAGT AAGCTGAGTN AGCTGAGTNG GCTGAGTNGG CTGAGTNGGA TGAGTNGGAC 
         1          1          1          1          1          1          1 
GAGTNGGACG AGTNGGACGC GTNGGACGCG TNGGACGCGA NGGACGCGAT GGACGCGATG GACGCGATGA 
         1          1          1          1          1          1          1 
ACGCGATGAT CGCGATGATG GCGATGATGC CGATGATGCG 
         1          1          1          1
```

Comment: Not sure though if you can use length(gregexpr()) as it will return 1 for non-matches also. E.g. if you omit function IUPACtoRX, it will return 1's for everyone also.

Comment: @aguiar True that, I forgot that gregexpr returns -1 in case of a mismatch. I've adapted

Comment: It would be cool if there was a solution with Biostrings though, because it's about 13 times faster!

Comment: You can try at https://www.biostars.org/ as well. I'm not that familiar with Biostrings and I have little time to go on a hunt, sorry